# Can sshd authenticate each incoming connection with both a key AND a password?

Tags: ssh, authentication, password, keys

I want to configure `sshd` to require that a connection authenticate with both a key and a password.

I haven't looked at using PAM or other external authentication methods yet, but my guess at the moment (based on `sshd_config(5)` is that this is not possible. Prove me wrong. Please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using openssh, I don't believe you can do this.  There are other SSH2 daemons out there which allow extended SSH2 directives giving you a directive called "RequiredAuthentications" and "AllowedAuthentications"; both of which are comma separated lists.  You can see a nifty chart of compatibility at:

http://hell.org.ua/Docs/oreilly/tcpip2/ssh/ch05_05.htm

If this is a requirement you have, you should change out your ssh daemon.  The config would then be:

```
AllowedAuthentications password,publickey
RequiredAuthentications password,publickey
```

Cheers

Comment: Keep in mind that doing it this way will require you to initiate the initial allowed public key, either by them providing their public key to you or you providing them with the private key.

Comment: OpenSSH does follow the SSH2 standard too, it simply doesn't implement "RequiredAuthentications".

Comment: @grawity - You're correct.  I have edited my answer to spread less FUD, thanks. :)

Comment: Also see [this answer over at serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/a/409758/64875). It looks like RHEL have patched openssh with similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an certificate with a pass phrase on it, then it will require you to enter that pass phrase when you log in with certificate authentication.

Comment: The command to do what Zypher mentioned above is "ssh-keygen". Here is the synopsis for the parts you would need: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] -t type [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]

Comment: However that is not actually a "key + password" setup for the SSH server, it is just a "key" setup.  The CLIENT is requesting a pass-phrase in order to access the private key when connecting to the SSH server.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because the passfrase can be trivially removed eg. ssh-keygen -P "old pass frase" -N "new pass frase" -f ssh-key-file

Comment: Thanks, but I only care about the server side. Key pass phrases have nothing to do with authentication, they just protect the key.

Answer (score 0):

http://novosial.org/openssh/publickey-auth/

Pay particular attention to 'Key Generation' for generating a key with a passphrase, and to 'Key Distribution' for enabling login to a given server with that passphrase-protected key